# SQL Query fails to function when using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I built this query to show me how many employees and customers to a branch, it gives me duplicates therefore I need to group them. However, the query is invalid when I add the group by. Anyone have any idea why?

```
  SELECT B.branchID, B.branchName, COUNT(E.staffNo) AS "No. Of Employees", COUNT(C.customerID) AS "No. Of Customers"
        FROM Branch B, Employee E, Customer C
        WHERE E.employeeBranchID = B.branchID
        AND B.branchID = C.customerBranchID
        GROUP BY B.branchID;
```

Comment: What do you mean "invalid"?  If you get an error, include the error in the question.

Comment: On mysql this should work,on other databases you need to add B.branchName to the GROUP BY

Answer (score 2):

This query would be better written as:

```
SELECT B.branchID, B.branchName, COUNT(E.staffNo) AS "No. Of Employees", COUNT(C.customerID) AS "No. Of Customers"
FROM Branch B JOIN
     Employee E
     ON E.employeeBranchID = B.branchID JOIN
     Customer C
     ON B.branchID = C.customerBranchID
GROUP BY B.branchID, B.branchName;
```

If you are in ANSI mode, then MySQL behaves like most other databases and will return an error because `B.branchName` is unaggregated.

Notes:

- Use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- All non-aggregated columns are in the `GROUP BY`.
- Your original query is ANSI compliant if `branchId` is declared as the primary or a unique key on `branch`.  However, most databases still do not accept the query.

Comment: I tried your method above unfortunately it doesn't work either `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Customer C
     ON B.branchID = C.customerBranchID
GROUP BY B.branchID, B.branch' at line 5`

Comment: There is an other "JOIN" missing before Customer C

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.branchID, B.branchName, COUNT(E.staffNo) AS "No. Of Employees", COUNT(C.customerID) AS "No. Of Customers"
    FROM Branch B, Employee E, Customer C
    WHERE E.employeeBranchID = B.branchID
    AND B.branchID = C.customerBranchID
    GROUP BY B.branchID, B.branchName;
```

Most DB require the list of group by items == the list of items in select before an aggregation function

Answer (score 0):

SELECT B.branchID, B.branchName, COUNT(E.staffNo) AS "No. Of Employees", COUNT(C.customerID) AS "No. Of Customers"
        FROM Branch B left join Employee E on E.employeeBranchID = B.branchID  left join Customer C on B.branchID = C.customerBranchID
        GROUP BY B.branchID;